# Push HTML Elements into an array to appendChild them later to a div which is also dynamically created

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, dynamic

I have some dynamically created elements.
I want to push these elements to an array to be able to for loop all of them and assign an attribute to each.

The problem is that if I declare an array like this `var Array = [];` I can't push an HTML element to it. Console log says that:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

If I declare the array like this `var Array;` then I can't push elements to it.

**Here is how I wanted to.**

```
var listgroupdiv  = document.createElement("div");
    var listgroupdiv1 = document.createElement("div");
    var listgroupdiv2 = document.createElement("div");


    var ListGroupClass = document.createAttribute("class");
    ListGroupClass.value = "row";
    listgroupdiv.setAttributeNode(ListGroupClass);
    var ListGroupClass1 = document.createAttribute("class");
    ListGroupClass1.value = "col-4";
    listgroupdiv1.setAttributeNode(ListGroupClass1);
    var ListGroupClass2 = document.createAttribute("class");
    ListGroupClass2.value = "list-group";
    listgroupdiv2.setAttributeNode(ListGroupClass2);
    var ListGroupID = document.createAttribute("id");
    var ListGroupRole = document.createAttribute("role");
    ListGroupID.value = "list-tab";
    ListGroupRole.value = "tablist";
    listgroupdiv2.setAttributeNode(ListGroupID);
    listgroupdiv2.setAttributeNode(ListGroupRole);

    var id_href = 0;
    var Array_A_Group = [];
    for(var b = 0; b < CommentArray.length; b++){
      if(CommentArray[b].indexOf("Parts:") > -1){
        var listgroupa        = document.createElement("a");
        var listgroupaClass   = document.createAttribute("class");
        var listgroupaID      = document.createAttribute("id");
        var listgroupaToggle  = document.createAttribute("data-toggle");
        var listgroupaHref    = document.createAttribute("href");
        var listgroupaRole    = document.createAttribute("role");
        var listgroupaAria    = document.createAttribute("aria-controls");

        listgroupaClass.value   = "list-group-item list-group-item-action";
        listgroupaID.value      = String(id_href);
        listgroupaToggle.value  = "list";
        listgroupaHref.value    = String(id_href);
        listgroupaRole.value    = "tab";
        listgroupaAria.value    = "home";
        listgroupa.setAttributeNode(listgroupaClass);
        listgroupa.setAttributeNode(listgroupaID);
        listgroupa.setAttributeNode(listgroupaToggle);
        listgroupa.setAttributeNode(listgroupaHref);
        listgroupa.setAttributeNode(listgroupaRole);
        listgroupa.setAttributeNode(listgroupaAria);

        var CommentText = document.createTextNode(CommentArray[b]);
        listgroupa.appendChild(CommentText);
        Array_A_Group[id_href].push(listgroupa); // <<-- Problem is in this line!
        
        id_href++;
      }
    }
```

**My goal is to create a div like this:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-messages-list">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-settings-list">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**With unique IDs and unique hrefs, and later add a TextNode to each `<a>`.**

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Are you aware of [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and its `add`-method?

Comment: Oh god that is really cool. :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem indeed is this line:

`Array_A_Group[id_href].push(listgroupa);`

The push method of the array object is called on the array itself.

e.g.

`Array_A_Group.push(listgroupa);`

The way you did, it tries to push the object to an array inside **Array_A_Group**
at the index **id_href**. Since this element doesn't exist you correctly get the error **Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

Furthermore you don't need to keep an additional variable to keep track of the array's index. After pushing something to an array it's index will increment automatically.

Comment: Oh god, thanks. That is pretty obvious now. I tried to push from the beginning for some reason and i created that variable. But that variable actually not just for that intent, i just used it in here too. But you have right. Thank you!

Comment: No problem Dr.Random - glad I could help! =)